# How to move file to download folder?

Tags: android, cordova

In my app I get `base64` data of a file (doc, pdf, jpeg,...) and write it with `FileWriter`.
The file is now in my app-directory. But I need to move it to the Download directory of Android device.
Is it not possible to get access with this code:

```
 window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL('content:///storage/emulated/0/Download', function(a) {},fail};
```

I always get error code 1.

In my android `manifest.xml` I currently just have `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. Is this enough?

Thanks. By the way I use **cordova3.4** and **android 4.3**.

Comment: I haven't seen cordova tag in it, I posted native code, which is removed now.

Answer (score 1):

The sdcard path changes from device to device.

I suggest you read the [File System plugin doc](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/dev/doc/index.md) for complete information.

If you haven't modified config.xml to add `<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal" />`, I'd say that this should do the job :

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI('/Download', function(dirEntry) {},fail};
```

Or an other way :

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
    function (fs) {
        fs.root.getDirectory("/Download", {
            create : false,
            exclusive : false
        }, function (dirEntry) { //success
            //do here what you need to do with Download folder
        }, function () {
            //error getDirectory
        });
    },
    function () {
    //error requestFileSystem
    }
);
```

Comment: Hello... Yes I add Internal to the config.xml... I suggest the issue is the url... Have you tested your code with cordova 3.4.. On my app its not workings

Comment: My code (the request filesystem way) is working with cordova 3.4 with the latest version of filesystem plugin. The thing is that if you set Internal, you don't access the SD card at all but internal memory (at least that's my understanding). I keek using "Compatibility" mode to be able to access SD card.

Comment: I am working with file api version 1.0.1... You too?

Comment: Hmm, but even if I change from Internal to Compatibility I get same error code...

Comment: Version 1.0.1 also. Have you tried with resolveLocalFileSystemURI or requestFileSystem?

Answer (score 0):

> this ll help u in Cordova to store file to ur requrired destination

public class FileDownload extends CordovaPlugin {

```
int serverResponseCode = 0;

ProgressDialog dialog = null;

String upLoadServerUri = null;
final String DownloadFilePath = null;
final String DownloadFileNameOne = null;
private final String PATH = "/storage/sdcard0/DestinationFoloder/";
public static final String ACTION_FILE_UPLOAD = "fileUploadAction";



@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args,CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
   try {
        if (ACTION_FILE_UPLOAD.equals(action)) {
            File dir = new File("/storage/sdcard0/Destination");
            if (dir.mkdir()) {

                Log.e("Directory created","DC");

            } else {
                Log.e("Directory Not created","DNC");

            }
            JSONObject arg_object = args.getJSONObject(0);
            String DownloadFilePath = arg_object.getString("path");
            String DownloadFileNameOne = arg_object.getString("NameDwn");
            fdownload(DownloadFilePath,DownloadFileNameOne);

            callbackContext.success("Attachment Download Sucessfully!");

        }
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        callbackContext.error(e.getMessage());
        return false;

    }

}



private boolean fdownload(String downloadFilePath2, String downloadFileNameOne2) {
    File FileCheck = new File(PATH+"/"+downloadFileNameOne2);

    if(FileCheck.exists()){

        return false;


    }else{

        try {
            URL url = new URL(downloadFilePath2); // you can write here
            // any
            // link
            Log.e("FilePath", "" + PATH + "" + downloadFileNameOne2);
            File file = new File("" + PATH + "" + downloadFileNameOne2);

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            URLConnection ucon;
            ucon = url.openConnection();
            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            /*
             * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to
             * read(-1).
             */
            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
            int current = 0;
            while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                baf.append((byte) current);
            }

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
            fos.close();
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }




    }

}
```

}

Comment: Again, I need the phonegap api way.

Comment: this class u can use in Phonegap by making Plugin

Comment: var FileDownload = {
    createEvent: function(path, NameDwn, successOneCallback, errorOneCallback) {
        cordova.exec(
            successOneCallback,
            errorOneCallback, 
            'FileDownload', 
            'fileUploadAction',
            [{                  
                  "path": path,
                  "NameDwn":NameDwn
               
               
                
            }]
        ); 
    }
}

Comment: use above code by mnaking js file and call the plugin class:- Hope This Helps

Comment: Thanks but I dont want to add a new plugin because phonegap file api can somehow do this too

Comment: window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL('file:///storage/emulated/0/Download', function(a) {},fail}

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the Cordova plugin: [cordova-plugin-file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file).  The specific file location is: cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + "Download/".  So apply window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL() to that.